# VBA - Instead of ActiveExplorer.Selection to set folder, explicitly set folder path

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

```
Sub MoveItems() 
    Dim Messages As Selection 
    Dim Msg As MailItem 
    Dim NS As NameSpace 
    Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
    Set Messages = ActiveExplorer.Selection 
    If Messages.Count = 0 Then
      Exit Sub 
    End If 
    For Each Msg In Messages 
      Msg.Move NS.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("SavedMail") 
    Next
End Sub
```

This code will move all email messages from the currently selected folder in Outlook to another folder (SavedMail).  I would like to edit the code so that instead of using the currently selected folder as the source for the messages, there would be a hard-coded folder - something like `Set Messages = NS.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Moved")`.

I'm a VBA rookie and tried just replacing the Set Messages line with this which resulted in a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch which I think refers to a mismatch of the Dim Messages and the Set Messages commands. I've tried using different Dim definitions with no luck.  I'm guessing that someone who knows VBA will see the way to do this right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're running into is the line

```
If messages.count = 0 then
```

Once defining `messages` as a folder, you can't count it - it wants to count a selection of mail items. Unless you need to handle errors like that, you could cut the code down like this -

```
Sub MoveItems() 
    Dim Msg As MailItem 
    Dim NS As NameSpace 
    Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
    For Each Msg In NS.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Moved").Items
      Msg.Move NS.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("SavedMail") 
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would assume that even if it could count messages.count, it wouldn't be useful anyway? OP goes into a foreach, if there is nothing to iterate over then it would skip it any way?

Comment: @Raystafarian it happens before any items are even processed. All items are mail items.  When I run the code included in my original post with the "Dim Messages As Selection", the code runs fine.  It is only when I explicitly define the path to the folder that I run into trouble.

Comment: @Raystafarian that seemed to make a difference.  I think it is the fix needed to explicitly define the folder. One more issue emerged. There are 25 email messages in the Moved folder, but only 13 are moved by the new, edited code. These 25 items were copied from the Inbox upon arrival using the outlook email rules.  The original code using the "Dim Messages As Selection" does move all 25.

Comment: @Raystafarian it looks like it is processing the first item and then skipping the next, and then processing the next, etc. I'm not sure how For Each works, but perhaps it is using a counter to process item number 1, then item number 2, etc. But, in processing item number 1, it moves item number 1 to a different folder.  This leaves what was item number 2 as now number 1.  So, when it next looks to process item 2, it is really going to process what was item 3 when the loop first started.

Comment: @Mike yeah, like I said you'll probably need to iterate backwards - [check this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox)

Comment: @Raystafarian that did the trick.  The link to the iterate backwards accepted answer was right on.

Comment: @Mike good to hear, sorry I couldn't throw the code in for you, I didn't have time last night.

Comment: @Raystafarian no problem.  You've been a great help.  I'd upvote you, but my reputation is too low.